# Не находит элементы в selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Пробую написать тест но не получаеться найти элемент(ы) 
[image: Где меня интересуют элемент либо "Czat" либо, если существует "Napisz wiadomosc"]
Где меня интересуют элемент либо "Czat" либо, если существует "Napisz wiadomosc"
Внизу способы которые пробовала, закомментировала, но пишет ошибку:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:\1\badoo\vremm_dla_prob2.py", line 33, in 
>       element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and
>   normalize-space(.)='Czatuj'])[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5ryG.png)/following::input[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5ryG.png)").click()   File
>   "C:\Users\Sylwia.thonny\BundledPython36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
>       return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)   File "C:\Users\Sylwia.thonny\BundledPython36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 978, in find_element
>       'value': value})['value']   File "C:\Users\Sylwia.thonny\BundledPython36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 321, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Users\Sylwia.thonny\BundledPython36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and
>   normalize-space(.)='Czatuj'])[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5ryG.png)/following::input[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5ryG.png)"}   (Session
>   info: chrome=70.0.3538.102)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210
>   (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT
>   6.1.7601 SP1 x86)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time,random

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

links = 'https://eu1.badoo.com/profile/0655060811'


driver.get('https://badoo.com/signin/?f=top')
time.sleep(10)


element = driver.find_element_by_name('email')#.click()


element.send_keys('21juliapl@gmail.com')#вводим значение

element = driver.find_element_by_name('password')#.click()


element.send_keys("$#R4353trt", Keys.ENTER)

time.sleep(15)

driver.get(links)#zapustit stranicu s perem links
#piszem
#try:
#element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#text-field > input[type="text"]').send_keys("hejka")


#element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('fast-message__content')#.send_keys("Hej", Keys.ENTER)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Czatuj'])[1]/following::input[1]").click()


#element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.fast-message__content')
#element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[input/@type='text']").send_keys("hejka")
#element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text']/input[0]").send_keys("hejka")
#element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='text-field__input']").send_keys("hejka")


    #driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.text-field__input')#.send_keys("hejka")
    #driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='text-field']/input[@type='text']").send_keys("hejka")#'Hej', Keys.ENTER
    #driver.find_element_by_class_name('fast-message__field-wrapper').send_keys("Hej", Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(5)
#except:
#    print ('piszem !!!PROBLEMY')
```

Пробовала через инспектор находить и через chrome katalon recorder, чтобы найти элементы.

Как найти эти элементы. и может подскажите инструменты которые помогают работать с selenium и находить элементы в коды, или проверять онлайн совпадают ли к примеру

find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='text-field__input']").send_keys("hejka")

с содержимым html кода

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте

```
#Элемент открывающий чат
element = driver.find_by_css_selector('div.profile-menu__item.profile-menu__item--chat')
```

Для второго варианта пришлите ссылку с таким сообщением